# Writing to multiple Kafka partitions from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have Spark code that writes a batch to Kafka as specified here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

The code looks like the following:

```
  df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") 
   \
   .write \
   .format("kafka") \
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 
           "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
   .option("topic", "topic1") \
   .save()
```

However the data only gets written to Kafka partition 0. How can I get it written uniformly to all partitions in the same topic ?

Comment: How many partitions does the topic actually have?

Comment: How many partitions in the topic? How many *distinct* `key`s are there in `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka distributes messages based on their keys. Therefore, messages with the same key will be placed into the same partition. It might be the case that all of your messages have the same key.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the insight.